# sh: 0: unknown operand when running shell script via docker

Tags: bash, docker

I have this code in a yaml file. This file gets run when I run docker.

```
if [[ $EXITCODE -ne 0 && "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "staging" ]] || [[ $EXITCODE -ne 0 && "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "develop" ]]; then
  echo "Hello"
fi
```

When I run these lines of code in my terminal it works as it should.
But when I run this file via docker, I get this error

`sh: 0: unknown operand`

What is happening here? Why am I getting this error? I've tried using different syntax for the $EXITCODE and the 0 but still getting the same error

Comment: Is `$EXITCODE` defined? Quote it.

Comment: Yes, when I run `echo $EXITCODE` it gives me a value

Comment: You ran the echo where, in your terminal or via docker? And where is that yaml, what is parsing it, compose, a CI tool?

Comment: Inside your docker container, run *sh --version* and let us know if it calls itself GNU bash, as well as the version, please. If your docker container's OS is not simply aliasing bash as sh, then Bashisms like double square brackets for testing, and double equals for equality will not work, as they're not POSIX compliant. See [this link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism) for common bashisms and how to translate to POSIX

Comment: If you have `bash`, I would avoid `-eq` and `-ne` inside `[[ ... ]]` if for no other reason than to improve readability. `if (( $EXITCODE != 0)) && [[ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "staging" ]]`, for example. In `bash`, though, `-ne` and `-eq`  both trigger arithmetic evaluation, which means that even if `EXITCODE` is not defined, then the empty string produced by `$EXITCODE` will be treated as an implicit `0`.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the info! Good to know!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your response!

So this works

```
if [[ "$EXITCODE" == "0" && "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "staging" ]] || [[ $EXITCODE -ne 0 && "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "develop" ]]; then
  echo "Hello"
fi
```

I guess it didn't like `-ne`.
However I have used

```
if [[ $EXITCODE -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo "Hello"
fi
```

and it has worked on its own. I guess you can't use it when there are other conditions and it's using the `==` or `!=`